# Wireless Card not working on Dell D620 w/ 15.10

Tags: wireless, dell

I bought a used lap top (Dell D620) for my daughter for Christmas and it works great accept after I loaded Ubuntu the wifi card is not there. It was there when windows was loaded but I wiped it. I have seen a few posts on the topic but the threads are a little confusing. Can anyone tell me how to get this lap top to see the wifi? I'm a little familiar with the terminal emulator on Ubuntu

Thanks

Comment: Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run `lspci -nn | grep 0280` Edit your question to add the result. Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: caitlyn@caitlyn:~$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
caitlyn@caitlyn:~$

Answer (score 0):

Typed in "b43 driver" in the Ubuntu software center and down loaded Firmware installer for the b43 driver and re-booted… poof the wifi is up and rolling